# How to locale correctly controlle AngularJS in page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are some items `div` at page:

```
<body>
<div id="block">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal"></div>
</body>
```

And one modal block `class="modal"` after all items.

I want that after click `.item` shows modal block, 
for this I have added `ng-controller="BlockController"` at parent block `id="block"`:

```
<div id="block" ng-controller="BlockController">
   ...
</div>
```

At modal block there are some buttons, which methods realization I want to add on controller `Block Controller`, but modal is not in border of visible controller.

Can I add yet same controller to: `<div class="modal" ng-controller="BlockController"></div>` to make common functionality in one controller?
I tried do this, but get troubles with visible `$scope` variables in this case:

**AnJS**

```
$scope.ClickSpam = function (id, type){
   $scope.id = id; // have value id
}
```

Template HTML:

```
{{id}} // here is not displayed value
```

Comment: why not use a global `div` that contains all your divs and modal, then you can add your `ng-controller="BlockController"` on it, or you can simply put it on your `body` tag if you don't have other controllers on your page

Comment: If use global it is not right, because I think each controller means sepatate functionality. Also I have some controller at page, so it will looks as any controllers are inside `BlockController`.

Comment: but as I see, your modal has to do with your `BlockConroller`, so it should be included there, shouldn't it ?

Comment: I could be create global controller, but know will appear any case when I will need use any global controller together. Modal window has `ng-controller` too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions you can do is to use another controller for your modal that contains its own features

```
<div class="modal" ng-controller="ModalController"></div>
```

now, inside the `BlockConroller` you can still access the `$scope` of `ModalController` like this :

```
angular.element($(".modal")).scope(); // returns ModalController's $scope
```

> Note that you have to use an id on your modal if you have many modals
>   with different controllers.

your code then would be like this :

**html code:**

```
<div class="modal" id="modalId" ng-controller="ModalController"></div>
```

**javascript code :**

```
angular.element($("#modalId")).scope(); // returns ModalController's $scope
```

---

Another problem you may find, is that is you change a variable which is the ModalController scope from your BlockController like this :

```
angular.element($(".modal")).scope().id = "something";
```

your `{{ id }}` binding will not work unless you call the `$apply` method :

```
angular.element($(".modal")).scope().$apply()
```

Comment: Maybe use `directive`?